# Static polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Impl>
struct renderer{
    void get(){
        static_cast<Impl*>(this)->get();
    }
};
struct open_gl : public renderer<open_gl>{
    void get(){
        std::cout << "OpenGL" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct direct_draw : public renderer<direct_draw>{
    void get(){
        std::cout << "DX" << std::endl;
    }
};
template<typename T>
void print_renderer(renderer<T> r){
    r.get();
}
int main() {
    auto gl = open_gl();
    auto dx = direct_draw();
    print_renderer(gl);
    print_renderer(dx);
}
```

1. Why can't I change the parameter of print_renderer to `void
   print_renderer(const renderer<T> &r)`? 
   `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const renderer<open_gl>' to 'renderer<open_gl> &'`
   `
2. Why do I get a runtime error when I rename the method `get` in open_gl from
   get to get1? Shouldn't this trigger a compiler error? `Error = Stack overflow`

**Note I am using the latest MSVC

Comment: And... mix-n-match!  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25722fa147efbbd3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1)** Because `get` is not a `const` member function : it cannot make the promise of not modify your (const) argument.

You could declare `get` as `const`, and it compiles fine :

```
void get() const { ... }
```

**2)** The base `get` method will be called, going into infinite recursion : Stack Overflow.

If you declare your function [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) (it needs to be virtual), the compiler will throw an error if it does not indeed override a base method :

```
void get1() override  { ... } // Compiler error
void get() override   { ... } // Ok
```

---

**Note:**

The title is "Static polymorphism in C++", but I think that you misunderstood what is static polymorphism : it does not (have to) make use of inheritance (as you did). Rather, the templates compile-time duck typing will statically "resolve" function calls for you.

That is, you don't need related types, you don't need the base `renderer` class at all, and you can simply do the following (in which case, renaming to `get1` *will* cause a compiler error) :

```
#include <iostream>

struct open_gl {
    void get(){
        std::cout << "OpenGL" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct direct_draw {
    void get(){
        std::cout << "DX" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void print_renderer(T r){
    r.get();
}

int main() {
    auto gl = open_gl();
    auto dx = direct_draw();
    print_renderer(gl);
    print_renderer(dx);
}
```

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/mG2MTO)**

Comment: Thanks, about my second question. Is it possible to throw a compiler error when `get` is not implemented? Something like override?

Comment: How can I make `void get()` virtual if I want static polymorphism?

Comment: @MaikKlein then you'll have to use templates machinery to statically check for the existence of `get` in a given type. Check [this anser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10958151/3510483).

Comment: @quantdev: Or, (my favorite) give the `renderer` members slightly different names.  Such as `void renderer::get(){static_cast<Impl*>(this)->get_();}`, and then you always get compiler errors if the function is not implemented in the derived class properly.

Comment: @quantdev I wasn't sure what the best practices are. Either I use templates with ducktyping and maybe do an assert `static_assert(is_renderer<T>,"")` or I do it with inheritance and CRTP. I'll create another question on SO for this.

Answer (score 5):

1. Becuase `get` is not marked `const`.
2. Because the base class method is used (irrelevantly of cast), and it goes into infinite loop.