# Static duck typing vs CRTP

Tags: c++, polymorphism

This is a follow up questions from [Static polymorphism in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559178/static-polymorphism-in-c)

- When should I prefer duck typing?
- When should I prefer CRTP?
- Are there any best practices?

It would boil down to this:

```
template<typename T>
void print_renderer(const renderer<T> &r){
    r.get();
}
```

vs

```
template<typename T>
void print_renderer(const T &r){
    static_assert(is_renderer<T>,"Not a renderer");
    r.get();
}
```

What I have observed so far:

- CRTP is not as nice to use as run-time polymorphism. To create an polymorphic interface someone has just to use `virtual` and `override`. Both of these keywords can't be used with CTRP. If I I have a typo in my implementation it will trigger a run-time error. (Maybe this can be prevented)
- Duck typing is really simple but it may confuse my clients. If they don't have access to the source code and they have to use `void print_renderer(T r)` vs `void print_renderer(renderer<T> r)` I think CRTP is much clearer.
- Duck typing does have a maintaining cost. In my previous question I created an `open_gl` and `direct_draw` implementation for my renderer. If I wanted to add another renderer for example `open_gl_es`, I would also have to change my `is_renderer<T>` function. But I don't think it would be too bad.

Comment: Don't use duct tape - weld it up.

Comment: Your example isn't CRTP.

Comment: @Simple I reused the code from my initial SO question that I have linked at the top. Should I copy the code into this one?

Comment: What you linked uses CRTP, yeah, but the bit you pasted isn't the CRTP bit. The CRTP bit is the `struct open_gl : public renderer<open_gl>`. Duck typing and CRTP are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: Yes but I use it in `print_renderer`. With CTRP I can make the type explicit in the parameter and that's what my question is about.

Comment: Also note that your example and the code you linked to is actually incorrect. `template<typename T> void print_renderer(renderer<T> r)` as well as `T r` will cause slicing. You should take by reference, as always when dealing with polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, just copied it from my old question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code sample where you take a `renderer<T>` by reference should be preferred. What you are doing in your second code sample is basically reimplementing overload resolution rules yourself.