# Polymorphism within a class method

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, run-time-polymorphism

Considering a struct `point`

```
struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}
```

and a class `object`

```
class object{
    public:
        std::vector<point> points;
        
        int dimension_count;

        void addPoint(point addedPoint);
};
```

I'd like to have several child classes, like
`line`, `plane`, and `shape` depending on the dimension count.

However, what I would like to do doesn't seem to have a way to implement it in valid C++.

In `addPoint()`, I'd like to automatically cast the `this` pointer to a subclass, either upcasting or downcasting as necessary.

```
void object::addPoint(point addedPoint){
     int tempDimensions = (int)(addedPoint.x != 0) + (int)(addedPoint.y != 0) + (int)(addedPoint.z != 0); 
     
     //this just casts to line, but it would handle dimensions 1, 2 and 3
     if(tempDimensions != dimension_count){
          if(tempDimensions == 1){
               this = dynamic_cast<line*>(this);
          }

     }
```

I'm aware that that is not valid C++, but I was wondering if there are any ways to do this, or if I'm stuck with an `if` statement at the beginning of each function, instead of using `virtual` functions to handle each case.

Comment: You may use [_static polymorphism_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559178/static-polymorphism-in-c) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change type of object at runtime, but you can change internal implementation of object at runtime. You can do something like this:

```
class base {
public:
  virtual void someFunc()= 0;
protected:
  std::vector<point> points;
};

class line {
public:
  line(base *old) {
    // convert from other versions here
  }
  virtual void someFunc() {
    ...
  }
};

class object {
public:
  void addPoint(point addedPoint); // This will be common function, but it can call in implementation specific if needed
  void someFunc() {pImpl->someFunc();} // This is "virtual" function
private:
  std::unique_ptr<base> *pImpl;
};

void object::addPoint(point addedPoint){
     int tempDimensions = (int)(addedPoint.x != 0) + (int)(addedPoint.y != 0) + (int)(addedPoint.z != 0); 
     
     //this just casts to line, but it would handle dimensions 1, 2 and 3
     if(tempDimensions != dimension_count){
          if(tempDimensions == 1){
               pImpl = std::make_unique<line>(pImpl.get());
          }
     }
}
```