# Check if static function is available in class at compile time

Tags: c++, type-traits

I am currently wiring an application that has several implementations for a single purpose. It is checked at runtime if the appropriate implementation can be used or if a fallback is used.

For that purpose I want all implementations to implement a static function `static bool is_available()`.

As static functions cannot be made abstract in the underlying base class, is there some preprocessor magic that will allow me to output an error message if the method is not statically implemented in the child class?

Comment: why is `is_available()` static?

Comment: Are you trying to enforce (at compile time) that all subclasses of a base have a static member function `is_available`?

Comment: I dont want to instanciate the classes unneeded. The `is_available` will simple check if libs can be loaded using `dlopen`, so there is no need yet to create an instance of that class to check the availability.

Comment: @Kerndog73 exactly

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957924/is-there-any-way-to-detect-whether-a-function-exists-and-can-be-used-at-compile should answer your question.

Comment: You might be able to use CRTP. All subclasses would have to inherit from `CanCheckAvailablility<MyClass>` (you'll think of a better name). The CRTP base would just call `is_available` in an unevaluated context and fail to compile if the function is not available. There might be better solutions. That's just the first that came to mind.

Comment: instead of using static function how about using virtual private functions in base class?

Comment: Won't this be enforced at compile-time by the code that calls `is_available`? I have a solution to a problem that I don't really understand.

Comment: I think this is http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: In order to check that the function exists, you will need to try to call it. Even if you use a CRTP base, you will still need to try to call a function on the base. That may be a destructor. You have to fully qualify a function to check if it exists so whatever check you perform will have to be done for each subclass. If you're writing a check in all the subclasses then you might as well just implement `is_available` in the all the subclasses! If you want an automatic check then you'll need to use an abstract virtual function. The compiler will ensure that it is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same vein that [user9400869's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921635/5470596), you can define a trait using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to check, at compilation time, the availability of your classes:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class LIB, class = void>
struct is_available
: std::false_type
{};

template<class LIB>
struct is_available<LIB, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r<bool, decltype(LIB::is_available)>::value>>
: std::integral_constant<bool, LIB::is_available()>
{};

template<class LIB>
constexpr bool is_available_v = is_available<LIB>::value;
```

This implies C++17 and `constexpr` functions `is_available` for the libs:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B { static constexpr bool is_available() { return false; } };
struct C { static constexpr bool is_available() { return true; } };

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_available_v<A> // 0
              << is_available_v<B> // 0
              << is_available_v<C> // 1 :)
              << '\n';
}
```

[Full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f0a9ac5745a1ed6)

---

If C++17 is not an option, you can implement [`std::is_invocable_r`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) using C++14 features only.

If `constexpr` static member functions are not an option for your library classes, you cannot rely on `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` and must use run-time result gathering:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class LIB, class = void>
struct is_available
{
    static bool value() { return false; }
};

template<class LIB>
struct is_available<LIB, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r<bool, decltype(LIB::is_available)>::value>>
{
    static bool value() { return LIB::is_available(); }
};
```

[Full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a85829a256b60b8a)

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH for this detailed answer! Solves my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

you could test this at compiletime with templates.
It goes something like this (sorry not tested):

```
template<class Type_to_test, class Technical_Detail = void>
struct has_isAvilable : std::false_type {}

template<class Type_to_test>
struct has_isAvilable<Type_to_test, std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_same<bool,decltype(Type_to_test::is_available())>::value
> > : std::true_type {}
```

Then you can use somewhere in your code:

```
static_assert(has_isAvilable<Implementation>::value,"Usefull error message");
```

Where Implementation is the class you wish to test.
Have a look at `std::type_traits` for examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an alternative: tag dispatching:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag {};

struct Base { /**/ };
struct Child1 : Base { /**/ };
struct Child2 : Base { /**/ };

bool is_available(Tag<Base>) {/*..*/}
bool is_available(Tag<Child1>) {/*..*/}
bool is_available(Tag<Child2>) {/*..*/}
```

`Tag` "blocks" Inheritance, contrary to:

```
struct Base { static constexpr bool is_available() { return false; } };
struct Child1 : Base { static constexpr bool is_available() { return true; } };
struct Child2 : Base { /**/ };

static_assert(Base::is_available() == false);
static_assert(Child1::is_available() == true);
static_assert(Child2::is_available() == false); // Call Base::is_available()
```